# Java StreamCorrupted when connecting more than one Client to Server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, multiplayer

## Explanation

I'm currently trying to create a Multiplayer Game with Java where up to five Players can play together.
The problem is that when I'm trying to connect multiple Clients to my Server I get an Exception and the Server doesn't work anymore.
With one Client at a time, everything works fine.

So what I need is a Server that can handle up to five players at a time and the clients should always get some new game data from the Server 
every few seconds (Connected Players, etc.).
The "Game data" in the code below is the String I'm sending through the Object Stream.
Normally I would send an Object which has all the game data, but with the String, I get the same problem.

I'm struggling with the problem that only one Client can connect without any errors occurring for some days now and I didn't find a solution to my problem.
I saw that there are things like java.nio or the ExecutorService, but I didn't really understand those that much, so I don't know if they can help.

I have made a smaller program that simulates the same problem I get with my bigger program.
To Start the Server, you need to Start the GameMultiPlayerCreate.java Class, and for the Client, the Client.java class.

I'm new to Sockets so if something is unnecessary or if something can be made better please let me know.

So the Error I'm getting when I connect two or more Clients is:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00050131
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Server.waitForData(Server.java:89) //I highlighted that in the code with a comment
    at Server.loopWaitForData(Server.java:49)
    at Server.run(Server.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

## Code

- GameMultiPlayerCreate.java: Should start the Server threads if a Client connects

```java
public class GameMultiPlayerCreate {
    ServerSocket socketServer = null;

    static String settingIp = "localhost";
    static String settingPort = "22222";
    static byte settingPlayers = 5;
    public static int connectedPlayers = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GameMultiPlayerCreate objGameMultiPlayerCreate = new GameMultiPlayerCreate();
            objGameMultiPlayerCreate.createServer();
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createServer() throws NumberFormatException, UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        while (connectedPlayers < settingPlayers) {
            socketServer = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(settingPort), 8, InetAddress.getByName(settingIp));
            System.out.println("Server is waiting for connection...");

            Socket socket = socketServer.accept();
            new Thread(new Server(socket)).start();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            socketServer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

- Server.java: This is the Class of which a new Thread should be created for each connected Client (Client Handler)

```java
public class Server implements Runnable {
    protected static Socket socket = null;

    private int loops;
    private int maxLoops = 10;
    private int timeout = 10000;
    protected static boolean killThread = false;
    private boolean authenticated = true; //true for testing

    protected static String ip;
    protected static int port;

    public Server(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        Server.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while trying to set Socket timeout. ");
            System.out.println("Closing Thread..." + Thread.currentThread());
            disconnectClient();
        }
        if (!killThread) {
            GameMultiPlayerCreate.connectedPlayers = GameMultiPlayerCreate.connectedPlayers + 1;
            loopWaitForData();
        }
    }

    private void disconnectClient() {
        System.out.println("Kicking Client... " + Thread.currentThread());
        killThread = true;
        GameMultiPlayerCreate.connectedPlayers = GameMultiPlayerCreate.connectedPlayers - 1;
    }

    public void loopWaitForData() {
        while (!killThread) {
            System.out.println(maxLoops + ", " + loops);
            if (maxLoops - loops > 0) {
                try {
                    waitForData();
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error occurred while waiting for Data. Thread disconnected? Sending reminder. " + Thread.currentThread());
                    if (!authenticated) {
                        System.out.println("Kicking Client: Not authenticated");
                        disconnectClient();
                    } else {
                        commandReminder();
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                    loops = loops + 1;
                    System.out.println("Error occurred while waiting for Data. Waiting for more Data. " + Thread.currentThread());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    loopWaitForData();
                }
            } else if (maxLoops - loops == 0) {
                System.out.println("Error occurred while waiting for Data. Maximum trys reached. Disbanding connection. " + Thread.currentThread());
                disconnectClient();
                loops = loops + 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Closing Thread..." + Thread.currentThread());
                disconnectClient();
            }
        }
    }

    private void commandReminder() {
        System.out.println("Reminder");
        try {
            String code = new String("0");
            ObjectOutputStream outputObject = new ObjectOutputStream(Server.socket.getOutputStream());
            outputObject.writeObject(code);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while trying to authenticate Client: " + e + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }

    public void waitForData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String code;
        System.out.println("Waiting for Data...");
        //Next line is where the error occurres
        ObjectInputStream inputObject = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while ((code = (String) inputObject.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Received Data...");
            System.out.println("Input received: " + code);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

- Client.java: This is the Client

```java
public class Client {
    public static Socket socket = new Socket();

    private int loops = 0;
    private int maxLoops = 10;
    private static boolean killThread = false;

    private String ip;
    private int port;

    public Client(String receivedIp, String receivedPort) {
        ip = receivedIp;
        port = Integer.parseInt(receivedPort);
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to Server...");
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while trying to connect to Server.");
        }
        loopWaitForData();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Client objClient = new Client("localhost", "22222");
    }

    public void loopWaitForData() {
        while (!killThread) {
            System.out.println(maxLoops + ", " + loops);
            if (maxLoops - loops > 0) {
                try {
                    waitForData();
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    loops = loops + 1;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                    }
                    System.out.println("Error occurred while waiting for Data. Waiting for more Data. " + Thread.currentThread());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    loopWaitForData();
                }
            } else if (maxLoops - loops == 0){
                System.out.println("Error occurred while waiting for Data. Maximum trys reached. Disbanding connection. " + Thread.currentThread());
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to close Socket " + Thread.currentThread());
                }
                loops = loops + 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Closing Thread..." + Thread.currentThread());
                killThread = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void waitForData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputObject = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        String code;
        System.out.println("Waiting for Data...");
        while ((code = (String) inputObject.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Received Data...");
            System.out.println("Input received: " + code);

            answer();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void answer() {
        try {
            String code = new String("1");
            ObjectOutputStream outputObject = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputObject.writeObject(code);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while trying to answer: " + e + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Socket socket;` should not be static in the server, and neither should anything else concerned with an individual client. The object streams should be instance variables, not local variables.

Comment: ... and should be created once per socket, not once per message.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for the answer i'll try that in a few mins. One Question: What is the technical reason for this? I mean why can't the socket be static and why should the stream only be created once per stream?

Comment: The accepted socket can't be static because otherwise you can correctly handle only one client, which is your immediate problem. The streams must be per-socket because they have stream headers which must be read exactly once, at a consistent time, and this is the easiest way to accomplish that; and it also economises on objects.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much for your answer! :)